# Node.js dirty Is it possible to reload a dirty database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-dirty

How do make the server reload the Dirty database when it's trying to get something from it? Because when I edit the database file with a text editor, and reload the browser, it doesn't update the page.

"reloadDB();" is where I want to reload the db.
**Code example**

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    var html = db.get(pathname);

    //Check if the requsted file is CSS or JS
    if (/\.(css)$/.test(pathname) || /\.(js)$/.test(pathname)){

        fs.createReadStream(__dirname + pathname, {
            'bufferSize': 4 * 1024
        }).pipe(response);

    } else if (!!html && pathname !== '/admin' ) {
        //Pages from our Dirty DB
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                    //reloadDB();
        response.end(html);
    } else if (pathname === '/admin') {
        //Display Admin page
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.end('Admin!');
    } else {
        //Show 404 Page
        response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        //reloadDB();
                    response.end(db.get('404'));
    }
```

Comment: And `reloadDB()` is... ?

Comment: It's just pseudo code to illustrate that I want to reload the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the `.Dirty(path)` method of your existing instance; if you look at the source, you'll see that there's a check allowing `Dirty()` to be used as either an instance method or a constructor.

Comment: Assuming this is the same code as in your earlier post, you'd just do `db.Dirty('pages.db')`.